# Is there a limit to the number of global resources registered in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

Is there a limit to the number of global resources I can register in Aurelia? I have a *resources/index.ts* that looks like

```ts
import {FrameworkConfiguration, PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration) {
  config.globalResources([
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/resource-1/resource-1'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/resource-2/resource-2'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/resource-2/resource-3/resource-3'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/resource-2/resource-3/inputs/resource-4/resource-4'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/resource-2/resource-3/inputs/resource-5/resource-5'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/resource-2/resource-3/inputs/resource-6/resource-6'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/resource-2/resource-3/inputs/resource-7/resource-7'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/resource-2/resource-3/inputs/resource-8/resource-8'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/resource-2/resource-3/inputs/resource-9/resource-9'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/resource-2/resource-3/inputs/resource-10/resource-10'),
  ]);
}
```

But when I inject `ViewResources` into my *app.ts* constructor and log it, I get

```
elements:
  compose: HtmlBehaviorResource {elementName: "compose", attributeName: null, attributeDefaultBindingMode: undefined, liftsContent: false, targetShadowDOM: false, …}
  resource-2: HtmlBehaviorResource {elementName: "resource-2", attributeName: null, attributeDefaultBindingMode: undefined, liftsContent: false, targetShadowDOM: false, …}
  resource-1: HtmlBehaviorResource {elementName: "resource-1", attributeName: null, attributeDefaultBindingMode: undefined, liftsContent: false, targetShadowDOM: false, …}
  resource-4: HtmlBehaviorResource {elementName: "resource-4", attributeName: null, attributeDefaultBindingMode: undefined, liftsContent: false, targetShadowDOM: false, …}
  resource-3: HtmlBehaviorResource {elementName: "resource-3", attributeName: null, attributeDefaultBindingMode: undefined, liftsContent: false, targetShadowDOM: false, …}
  router-view: HtmlBehaviorResource {elementName: "router-view", attributeName: null, attributeDefaultBindingMode: undefined, liftsContent: false, targetShadowDOM: false, …}
```

I confirmed that the paths are all correct. For example, weirdly enough, if I comment out the `resource-4` line in *index.ts* then `ViewResources` will just show resources 1, 2, 3 & 5 instead. Just goes down the line.

Any thoughts on this weird behavior?

Comment: There's none. The reason you saw that is probably because some other stuff going on. Maybe if you can have a simple repro,It'll be easier to find out

Comment: Need more to work with, there is no limit to the number of registered resources so there is a bug somewhere else